# Reading files name from file in Java

Tags: java, file

How can I read the names of the text files from a text file from which I want the texts are to be read?

for example, I have file.txt that has the names of several files inside it like text1.txt,txt2.txt...
so I want to read all the texts from these textfiles.
how can I do that in java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Java string from the contents of a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326390/how-do-i-create-a-java-string-from-the-contents-of-a-file)

Comment: can you maybe show what you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read all the text file names from file.txt and store them in a arraylist; then use each element of the arraylist as the path you gave to the FileReader.

```
public ArrayList<String> readWordsFromFile(){
    ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("file.txt");
        Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(fileReader);
        text.add(fileIn.nextLine());

        fileIn.close();
        return text;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File Not Found");
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then :

```
ArrayList<String> names = readWordsFromFile();
for(String name: names){
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(name);
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(fileReader);
    //and do what ever you want with the text file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need java.io

```
 import java.io.*;
    public class read {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
            FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String zeile1 = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(zeile1);
            String zeile2 = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(zeile2);
            String zeile3 = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(zeile3);

            br.close();

        }

    }
```

Comment: use a loop = String row= null; 
         while ((row= br.readLine()) != null) { 
             System.out.println("read lines: " + row);
         }

Answer (score 0):

You could read all lines using the newer `java.nio.*` packages

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class ReadFiles {

  public static void main( String[] args ){
    Path filePath = Paths.get( "/path/to/file", "file.txt" );

    Charset charset = Charset.forName( "UTF-8" );

    try{
      List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines( filePath, charset );

      // all the filenames are now in the list
      // let's print them out to console.
      for( String line : lines ){
        System.out.println( line );
      }
    }catch( IOException e ){
      System.out.println( e );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That not really new ;) it's from java 7. Upgraded with functional features in java 8.

Comment: @AxelH - I didn’t say it was **new**; said it was ***newer*** (than `java.io.*;`) likely I was thinking like that because previous answers made reference to the older package

Answer (score 0):

To read a file, I would use [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-). This is quite simple and provide some methods that allow you to read each line easily :

```
// Get the path for the file
Path path = Paths.get( "/tmp/files.txt" );
// Read a file a print in console.
Files.lines(path) //get a `Stream<String>`
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Now, in your case, you need to distinct action, for each line, you want to read another file. So let use a method that read a file and execute an action for each line :

```
public static void readFile(Path path, Consumer<String> action) {
    try {
        Files.lines(path).forEach(action);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

And this will be quite simple to use. For each line of the first file, we call the method to print each line in the console with `(s) -> readFile(Paths.get(s), System.out::println)`.

```
Path path = Paths.get( "/tmp/files.txt" );
readFile(path, (s) -> readFile(Paths.get(s), System.out::println));
```

That will be a recursive call using another action to print the content.

/tmp/files.txt

```
/tmp/file1.txt
/tmp/file2.txt
/tmp/file3.txt
```

/tmp/file1.txt

```
Hello world
```

/tmp/file3.txt

```
Foo bar
```

> Hello world
> Foo bar
> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /tmp/file2.txt